# T-SQL GO Statement n Times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have seen many examples and notes where people state you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO DatesTable  
   SELECT DateAdd(day, 1, MAX(DatesTable.Dates)) from DatesTable
GO 10
```

GO n times I hear is a valid way of looping in SQL - but it doesn't work and SQL Server Management Studio doesn't allow it.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a setting I'm not aware of? And if it cannot be done, what is the simplistic alternative.

Comment: it works just fine for me in SQL Server Management Studio - but **only** there (and in the other SQL Server tooling) since `GO` is **not** a SQL/T-SQL keyword, but rather a SSMS / SQLCMD specific "delimiter"

Comment: SSMS *Intellisense* doesn't like it, but it runs fine in my experience. Also, to nit @marc_s's comment, it's also defined in the other client tools, such as SqlCmd.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you're nit-picky - but right, of course :-)

Comment: I started a connect item to make it work everywhere not just ssms): https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3138257/make-go-a-first-class-language-keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheers for confirming its valid people.
I found the reason why it didnt want to work - GO simply wants another statement after it so I did a select to see its worked and it allows it all to run - simple and useful.

```
INSERT INTO DatesTable  SELECT DateAdd(day, 1, MAX(DatesTable.Dates)) from DatesTable
GO 10
SELECT * FROM DatesTable
```

Answer (score 0):

In general using a single sql query is more performant and maintainable/adaptable than using a loop.

One mechanism is to use a lookup table that holds a sequence of numbers. One such undocumented but useful table is `master..spt_values`.

```
INSERT INTO
  DatesTable
SELECT
  DATEADD(DAY, SEQUENCE.number, BASE.date)
FROM
  master..spt_values                            AS SEQUENCE
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(Dates) AS date FROM DatesTable)   AS BASE
WHERE
      SEQUENCE.type = 'P'
  AND SEQUENCE.number BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```